# Blinking visibility of icons in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, icons

I not see correctly icons on panel - only when unhover mouse.

Problem on video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsSXoVQwwq0

I have this:

[image]

but need this (see only 1/10 of seconds - see on video):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have checked either by accident or intentionally "hide when not in use"  To see the LXPanel all of the time, right click an open space on the LXPanel.  Choose Panel Settings and then Advanced.  Untick minimize panel when not in use.  Close and you should be good to go.

Comment: No, I want hide panel when I not need it - problem only with icons (for example Wi-Fi) - when I see panel I want to see all my icons (on video you can see all icons in 1/10 of seconds, when I "un-hover" mouse from panel). I have black panel on this video and black desktop background.